# Dropbox-like bash script

Tags: bash, synchronization

I am trying to write a bash script that synchronizes two folders similar to what the Dropbox service does, namely delete the files/folders not present in the newest folder and copies the newest stuff.
However I am not sure on how to deal with path/filenames. So I am asking some advice from you, also on possibly improving the script. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=/dev/stdout
#outerr=/dev/stderr
outerr="test.txt"

if [  $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Not enough arguments passed to the script, try again next time." >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Usage: " >> $out
    echo "   bash files_sync.sh [--t] SOURCE_NEW DESTINATION_OLD " >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Options: --t  just prints the modifications, without taking any action" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 1
fi

test=0

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then 
    source=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed  's/\///')
    dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$2")
    #dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$2" | sed  's/\///')
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then 
    if [ $1 == "--t" ]
    then
        echo "" >> $out
        echo "   Printing the suggested actions..." >> $out
        test=1 
        source=$(printf '%s\n' "$2" | sed  's/\///')
        dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$3")
    else
        echo "   What's your game, dude? Exiting. " >> $out
        exit 20
    fi
    #source=$(printf '%s\n' "$2" | sed  's/\///')
    #dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$3" | sed  's/\///')
fi

if [ ! -d $source ]; then 
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Path $source does not exists or not a folder, exiting. " >>         $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 2
else
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   (SOURCE) UP-TO-DATE FOLDER: $source" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
fi

if [ ! -d $dest ]; then 
    echo "   Path $dest does not exists or not a folder, exiting. " >>     $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 3
else
    echo "   (DESTINATION) TO BE SYNCHED FOLDER: $dest" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
fi

echo -n "   Do you REALLY want to proceed? [y/N] : " >> $out
read choice
echo "" >> $out

if [ $choice == "n" ]; then
    echo "   Brilliant, bye!" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 4
fi

if [ $choice == "y" ]
then
    echo "   Awesome! Let's get started ...."
    #FIRST CHECK IF DEST FILES ARE IN SOURCE. IF NOT DELETING THEM

    list1=`find $source -mindepth 1 -name "*" | sed 's/'"$source"'\///'`
    list2=`find $dest -mindepth 1 -name "*"`
    #list2=`find $dest -mindepth 1 -name "*" | sed 's/'"$dest"'\///'` 

    outdest="testdest.txt"
    echo "  Writing DEST files into $outdest file" >> $out
    > $outdest
    for filedest in $list2
    do
        echo $filedest >> $outdest
    done
    outsrc="testsrc.txt"
    echo "  Writing SRC files into $outsrc file" >> $out
    > $outsrc
    for filesrc in $list1
    do
        echo $filesrc >> $outsrc
    done

    outerr="testerr.txt"
    >$outerr
    echo "  Writing operations into $outerr file" >> $out

    for filedest in $list2
    do
        #if [ ! -d $filedest ]
        #then
            check="true"
            for filesrc in $list1
            do
                #if [ ! -d $filesrc ]
                #then
                    if [ $filedest == $filesrc ]
                    then
                        check="false"
                        break
                    fi
                #fi
           done
                if [ $check == "true" ]
                then 
                if [ $test -eq 1 ]
                then        
                    echo "rm $dest/$filedest"  >> $outerr
                else
                    echo " ! "; rm $dest/$filedest
                fi
            fi
    #fi
    done
    #THEN CHECK IF FILE IN SOURCE IS IN DEST. IF NOT COPY ELSE CHECK IF IT IS NEWER
    for filesrc in $list1
    do
        check="true"
        for filedest in $list2
        do              
            if [ $filedest == $filesrc ]
            then
                check="false"
                if [ $source/$filesrc -nt $dest/$filedest ] 
                then 
                    if [ -d $source/$filesrc ]
                    then
                        echo " folder here, do nothing"  >> $outerr
                    else
                        if [ $test -eq 1 ]
                        then        
                            echo "cp $source/$filesrc $dest/$filedest"  >> $outerr
                        else
                            echo " ! "; cp $source/$filesrc $dest/$filedest
                        fi

                    fi
                fi
                #break
            fi
        done
        if [ $check == "true" ]
        then
            if [ $test -eq 1 ]
            then        
                #echo -n "   +++ $source/$filesrc not existing in DEST : "  >> $outerr
                if [ -d $source/$filesrc ]
                then
                    echo "mkdir $dest/$filesrc"  >> $outerr
                else
                    echo "mv $source/$filesrc $dest/ "  >> $outerr
                fi
            else
                if [ -d $source/$filesrc ]
                then
                    echo " ! "; mkdir $source/$filesrc
                else
                    echo " ! "; mv $source/$filesrc $dest/$filedest
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done

    echo ""  >> $out
    echo '   --------- Sync COMPLETE ! -------------' >> $out
    echo ""  >> $out
   else
        echo ""  >> $out
        echo '   Not getting the answer. Exiting'  >> $out
        echo ""  >> $out
   fi
```

Thank you in advance,

Aldo

Comment: Are you aware of `rsync`?

Comment: for what I am aware it does not remove files in the target folder not present in the source.

Comment: `--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reduced the meat of the script down to a single loop.  I think I am doing what you want.  I changed all of:

```
if [ something ]
then
```

to `if [something ]; then`.  I think it made all the indentation easier to read.  I deleted the pre-removing logic, and added a loop after all the copying is complete. So this whole loop is gone:

```
for filedest in $list2
    do
        #if [ ! -d $filedest ]
        #then
            check="true"
            for filesrc in $list1
            do
                #if [ ! -d $filesrc ]
                #then
                    if [ $filedest == $filesrc ]
                    then
                        check="false"
                        break
                    fi
                #fi
           done
                if [ $check == "true" ]
                then 
                if [ $test -eq 1 ]
                then        
                    echo "rm $dest/$filedest"  >> $outerr
                else
                    echo " ! "; rm $dest/$filedest #logic error here.
                fi
            fi
    #fi
    done
```

Another major change is all the quoting and the changing of the internal field separator (IFS).  (Edit: I changed using `find` to glob (`*`) so there is no need to change the IFS)  These are all necessary to ensure that you can handle file names with spaces in them.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=/dev/stdout
#outerr=/dev/stderr
#outerr="test.txt"


function sync_dir 
{
    #This is our current subdirectory of $source and $dest.
    #Note: In the original call we do not pass an argument so $subdirs is blank.
    #This means that "$source/$subdirs"* = "$source/"* for the original call.
    local subdirs="$1"
    
    #By removing these find calls, we can just use * and avoid making changes to the IFS
    #local list1=`find "$source/$subdirs" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*"`
    #local list2=`find "$dest/$subdirs" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*"`
    
    #No need for find.  Let * do all the work.
    for filesrc in "$source/$subdirs"*; do 
        echo "$filesrc" >> $outsrc
        #remove path from $filesrc
        local filewithoutdir="$(basename "$filesrc")"           
        #if "$filesrc" is a directory
        if [ -d "$filesrc" ]; then
            #check to see if the destination is a directory. Make it if not...
            if [ ! -d "$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" ]; then   
                if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then            
                    echo "mkdir \"$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir\"" >> $outerr
                else
                    echo " ! "; mkdir "$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" 2>> $outerr
                fi
            fi
            #recursive call if we are dealing with a directory.
            sync_dir "$subdirs$filewithoutdir/"
        #else if not a file OR "$filesrc" is newer than the destination, copy it.
        elif [ ! -f "$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" -o "$filesrc" -nt "$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" ]; then 
            if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then        
                echo "cp \"$filesrc\" \"$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir\""  >> $outerr
            else
                echo " ! "; cp "$filesrc" "$dest/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" 2>> $outerr
            fi
        fi
    done
    #Here we loop throught the destination directory
    for filedest in "$dest/$subdirs"*; do
        echo "$filedest" >> $outdest
        local filewithoutdir="$(basename "$filedest")"
        #If the files do not exist in the source directory, delete them.
        if [ ! -e "$source/$subdirs$filewithoutdir" ]; then
            if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then        
                echo "rm -f \"$filedest\" >/dev/null 2>&1"  >> $outerr
            else
                #We allow this to fail and silence it because it may try to delete a directory.
                echo " ! "; rm -f "$filedest" >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
            
        fi
        #if you want to remove files and directories use this, but this can be dangerous.
        #if [ ! -e $source/$filewithoutdir ]; then
        #    if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then        
        #        echo "rm -rf \"$filedest\" >/dev/null 2>&1"  >> $outerr
        #    else
        #        echo " ! "; rm -rf "$filedest" 2>> $outerr
        #    fi
        #    rm -rf "$filedest" >/dev/null 2>&1
        #fi
    done  
}

if [  $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Not enough arguments passed to the script, try again next time." >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Usage: " >> $out
    echo "   bash files_sync.sh [--t] SOURCE_NEW DESTINATION_OLD " >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Options: --t  just prints the modifications, without taking any action" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 1
fi

test=0

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    #This will cause an issue when processing full path like /home/user/bla
    #source=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed  's/\///')
    #dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$2")
    #dest=$(printf '%s\n' "$2" | sed  's/\///')
    source="$1"
    dest="$2"
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
    if [ $1 == "--t" ]; then
        echo "" >> $out
        echo "   Printing the suggested actions..." >> $out
        test=1 
        source="$2"
        dest="$3"
    else
        echo "   What's your game, dude? Exiting. " >> $out
        exit 20
    fi
fi

if [ ! -d $source ]; then 
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   Path $source does not exists or not a folder, exiting. " >>         $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 2
else
    echo "" >> $out
    echo "   (SOURCE) UP-TO-DATE FOLDER: $source" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
fi

if [ ! -d $dest ]; then 
    echo "   Path $dest does not exists or not a folder, exiting. " >>     $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 3
else
    echo "   (DESTINATION) TO BE SYNCHED FOLDER: $dest" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
fi

echo -n "   Do you REALLY want to proceed? [y/N] : " >> $out
read choice
echo "" >> $out

if [ $choice == "n" ]; then
    echo "   Brilliant, bye!" >> $out
    echo "" >> $out
    exit 4
fi

if [ $choice == "y" ]; then
    echo "   Awesome! Let's get started ...."
    
    outdest="testdest.txt"
    echo "  Writing DEST files into $outdest file" >> $out
    > $outdest
    
    outsrc="testsrc.txt"
    echo "  Writing SRC files into $outsrc file" >> $out
    > $outsrc
    
    outerr="testerr.txt"    
    echo "  Writing operations into $outerr file" >> $out
    >$outerr
    
    #function call
    sync_dir
    
    #If we are not in test mode and errors have occured, they will be written to $outerr.
    #This test (-s) checks to see that $outerr is not zero length (implies -e).
    if [ ! $test -eq 1 -a -s $outerr ]; then
      echo "WARNING: Errors have occured during the running of this script.  See $PWD/$outerr for details" >> $out
    fi
    
    echo ""  >> $out
    echo '   --------- Sync COMPLETE ! -------------' >> $out
    echo ""  >> $out
else
    echo ""  >> $out
    echo '   Not getting the answer. Exiting'  >> $out
    echo ""  >> $out
fi
```

Currently, this will not copy the contents of a directory in the source.  If that is what you want, you could put the meat of this thing in a function.  Then `cd` into the destination directories and recursively call the function to copy over the sub-directory's contents as well.

Edit: Now implemented the recursive version.  My earlier version is actually wrong.  I misread -mindepth as -maxdepth.  -maxdepth would have prevented us from reading passed the first directory.  The edited code will actually work with sub-directories and full path directories.

You will also notice I added `2>> $outerr` to the end of `cp`, `rm` and `mkdir` calls.  This will catch any output to stderr and write it to `$outerr`.  Remember, all of these commands can fail, so it is important to at least catch the errors.  In test mode, you were printing all the actual commands that would be used into `$outerr`.  You weren't using it at all when not in test mode so I populate it with any errors that may occur during the processing.  At the end we check `-s $outerr` to see if any errors have been reported and post a little warning.  If you want to play it safe, you change `2>> $outerr` to `2>> $outerr || exit 2` to force an exit on any errors.

Comment: So it should be better not to remove the backslash in the path?

Comment: I found it easier this way. There were some logic errors in your code where the result became `cp <sourcedir>/<sourcedir>/<file> `which would obviously fail. This was due to the source list being piped into sed and not the destination list. So the lists were different, but their logic was treated the same. I chose this method because it eliminated the nested for loops.  The simpler the better especially since I reassigned the IFS.

Comment: Sorry. The error was here `cp $source/$filesrc $dest/$filedest`. Where this expands to the correct source file but the destination expands to `<destdir>/<destdir>/<file>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing this script for an assignment or just for learning how to code a bash script, then Jason has already made a very helpful reply. Also please ignore the rest of my post as it does not answer your question.

If you just want a tool for synchronizing two folders, then `rsync` is for you.
For example I use the following script in order to sync my music to an external drive

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -aE --delete /home/user/Music/  /media/user/data/my.lib/music
```

`--delete` is used for deleting target files and folders that are not present in the source folder tree. There is also an option for deleting these files after the syncing is done (`delete-after`). You can also use the `--dry-run` option in order to not perform any actual change. 
`-aE` is for recursing into folders, preserving file permissions, modification times, executability, links, owner, and group.

Why not build your own script? For three reasons. First, there is no reason to reinvent the wheel. Second, a tool like `rsync` is well tested and debugged. Third, we are talking about your files... ;-)

Comment: I wanted to practice and having some kind of interactive file-to-file choice of action as well. For practical purposes, it will more robust (and safer!) to stick to rsync